# Customizing Gviz's plotTracks function

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor, cowplot

I'm trying to generate a track plot using `Gviz`'s `plotTracks` function.

For example, I'm trying to plot these three transcripts from [gencode.v25.primary_assembly.annotation.gtf](ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/gencode/Gencode_human/release_25/gencode.v25.chr_patch_hapl_scaff.annotation.gtf.gz):

```
"ENST00000352151.9","ENST00000550488.5","ENST00000335154.9"
```

(all from gene: `ENSG00000161791.13`)

So I'm trying to call `GeneRegionTrack` with a data.frame that includes only the `GTF` records of these three transcripts:

```
require(rtracklayer)
#gtf.fn is the gencode.v25.primary_assembly.annotation.gtf file
gtf.df <- as.data.frame(import(gtf.fn))
my.transcripts.gtf.df <- dplyr::filter(gtf.df, transcript_id %in% c("ENST00000352151.9","ENST00000550488.5","ENST00000335154.9"))


> dim(my.transcripts.gtf.df)
[1] 171  27
```

And (naively) trying `GeneRegionTrack` with `my.transcripts.gtf.df`:

```
require(Gviz)
gene.region.track <-GeneRegionTrack(range=my.transcripts.gtf.df,genome="hg38",chromosome=my.transcripts.gtf.df$seqnames[1],name="Gene Model")
ideogram.track <- IdeogramTrack(genome=genome,chromosome=as.character(t.df$chromosome[1]))
plotTracks(list(ideogram.track,axis.track,gene.region.track))
```

I get a bit of a mess:
[image]

That's because the `GTF` has more records than the CDS/exon/UTR records which will make `plotTracks` more organized.

I tried:

```
my.transcripts.gtf.df <- dplyr::filter(gtf.df, transcript_id %in% c("ENST00000352151.9","ENST00000550488.5","ENST00000335154.9"), type %in% c("CDS","exon","UTR"))
gene.region.track <-GeneRegionTrack(range=my.transcripts.gtf.df,genome="hg38",chromosome=my.transcripts.gtf.df$seqnames[1],name="Gene Model")
plotTracks(list(ideogram.track,axis.track,gene.region.track))
```

And I get:
[image]

Which is still quite a mess. But what I do notice is that the 3'UTRs seem to have the same width as the all exons.

So I tried to process my `GTF` to make it compatible with that `Gviz` has in its [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Gviz/inst/doc/Gviz.pdf):

```
determineGtfFeature <- function(t.gtf.df){
  if(length(which(unique(t.gtf.df$type) == "CDS")) > 0){
    res.gtf.df <- dplyr::filter(t.gtf.df,type =="CDS")
    res.gtf.df$type <- NA
    res.gtf.df$type <- "protein_coding"
    if(length(which(unique(t.gtf.df$type) == "UTR")) > 0){
      utr.gtf.df <- dplyr::filter(t.gtf.df,type == "UTR")
      utr.gtf.df <- utr.gtf.df[order(utr.gtf.df$start),]
      if(utr.gtf.df$strand[1] == "+"){
        utr5.idx <- which(utr.gtf.df$end < min(res.gtf.df$start))
        utr3.idx <- which(utr.gtf.df$start > max(res.gtf.df$end))
      } else{
        utr3.idx <- which(utr.gtf.df$end < min(res.gtf.df$start))
        utr5.idx <- which(utr.gtf.df$start > max(res.gtf.df$end))
      }
      utr.gtf.df$type <- NA
      utr.gtf.df$type[utr5.idx] <- "utr5"
      utr.gtf.df$type[utr3.idx] <- "utr3"
      res.gtf.df <- rbind(res.gtf.df,utr.gtf.df)
    }
  } else{
     if(grepl("pseudogene",t.gtf.df$transcript_type)==T){
       res.gtf.df <- dplyr::filter(t.gtf.df,type =="exon")
       res.gtf.df$type <- "pseudogene"
     } else{
       res.gtf.df <- dplyr::filter(t.gtf.df,type =="exon")
       res.gtf.df$type <- "lincRNA"
     }
  }
  res.gtf.df$type <- factor(res.gtf.df$type,levels=unique(res.gtf.df$type))
  res.gtf.df <- res.gtf.df[,-which(colnames(res.gtf.df) == "transcript_type")]
  return(res.gtf.df)
}
```

And then:

```
my.transcripts.gtf.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(c("ENST00000352151.9","ENST00000550488.5","ENST00000335154.9"),function(t)
  determineGtfFeature(dplyr::select(dplyr::filter(gtf.df, transcript_id == t),seqnames,start,end,width,strand,type,gene_id,exon_id,transcript_id,gene_name,transcript_type))))
colnames(my.transcripts.gtf.df)[c(1,6,7,8,9,10)] <- c("chromosome","feature","gene","exon","transcript","symbol")
tid.starts <- sort(sapply(unique(my.transcripts.gtf.df$transcript),function(t) min(dplyr::filter(my.transcripts.gtf.df,transcript == t)$start)))
my.transcripts.gtf.df$transcript.index <- sapply(my.transcripts.gtf.df$transcript,function(t) which(names(my.transcripts.gtf.df) == t))
my.transcripts.gtf.df <- my.transcripts.gtf.df[order(my.transcripts.gtf.df$transcript.index,my.transcripts.gtf.df$start),]
my.transcripts.gtf.df <- my.transcripts.gtf.df[,-which(colnames(my.transcripts.gtf.df) == "transcript.index")]
my.transcripts.gtf.df$gene <- factor(my.transcripts.gtf.df$gene,levels=unique(my.transcripts.gtf.df$gene))
my.transcripts.gtf.df$exon <- factor(my.transcripts.gtf.df$exon,levels=unique(my.transcripts.gtf.df$exon))
my.transcripts.gtf.df$transcript <- factor(my.transcripts.gtf.df$transcript,levels=unique(my.transcripts.gtf.df$transcript))
my.transcripts.gtf.df$symbol <- factor(my.transcripts.gtf.df$symbol,levels=unique(my.transcripts.gtf.df$symbol))
```

So:

```
gene.region.track <- GeneRegionTrack(range=my.transcripts.gtf.df,genome=genome,chromosome=as.character(t.df$chromosome[1]),name="Gene Model")
plotTracks(list(ideogram.track,axis.track,gene.region.track))
```

Now gives:
[image]

Only `utr3` of the middle transcript has the proper smaller width but the other two don't.

As far as I checked `my.transcripts.gtf.df` is compatible with:

```
 data(geneModels)
```

used in `Gviz`'s [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Gviz/inst/doc/Gviz.pdf).

So my questions are:

1. Is there a simple way to get `Gviz` to plot a requested `transcript` from a standard `GTF` file without having to go through the trouble of editing it. Probably not, and hence the `GTF` needs to be in the same format as the `geneModels` `data.frame`. So any idea why are the utr3's misbehaving?
2. Which parameter in `displayPars(gene.region.track)` controls the spacing between the tracks? If I set `displayPars(gene.region.track)$stackHeight <- 0.1` the tracks become narrower which leaves a big space between them, and I would like to shrink that space.